# Unable to determine the session we are in

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, wayland, polkit

I am currently running GarudaLinux(ArchLinux) , with Wayland and Hyprland as WM.

Somewhere while disabling my GPUs adding Virtualization I lost my polkit configuration, and I am no longer able to run the agent:

`/usr/lib/polkit-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1`

I get the following result:

````
(polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:4805): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: 02:46:05.776: Unable to determine the session we are in: No session for pid 4805```
````

Running:
loginctl

```
SESSION  UID USER     SEAT  TTY  STATE  IDLE SINCE
      2 1000 echeleon seat0 tty1 active no
```

PolkitService Status

```
systemctl status polkit.service

● polkit.service - Authorization Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/polkit.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-09-03 02:45:27 BST; 14min ago
       Docs: man:polkit(8)
   Main PID: 1015 (polkitd)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 75983)
     Memory: 7.5M
        CPU: 95ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/polkit.service
             └─1015 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug

Sep 03 02:45:27 echeleon systemd[1]: Starting Authorization Manager...
Sep 03 02:45:27 echeleon polkitd[1015]: Started polkitd version 123
Sep 03 02:45:27 echeleon polkitd[1015]: Loading rules from directory /etc/polkit-1/rules.d
Sep 03 02:45:27 echeleon polkitd[1015]: Loading rules from directory /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d
Sep 03 02:45:27 echeleon polkitd[1015]: Finished loading, compiling and executing 11 rules
Sep 03 02:45:27 echeleon polkitd[1015]: Acquired the name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 on the system bus
Sep 03 02:45:27 echeleon systemd[1]: Started Authorization Manager.
```

I am honestly quite new to all this so I am lost on what to do/search.

What can I try, or search for? Looking online there are mentions of `elogind` - but this was working before, and I am not sure exactly what to do to get it to work.

Any pointers, apreciated.